# Facebook app review using simulator build and OpenGraph custom stories

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk

I've configured a custom story for my iOS app using the Facebook SDK. The problem is now I need to go through revision to get the verbs and objects approved, and the app is not yet in the App store.

I can of course upload a simulator build, but as far as I know it's not possible to install the native Facebook app in the simulator, and the custom story posting does not work if the app is not installed (it can fall back to regular posting, but I'm not interested), so right now you can only experience the custom story posting with an actual device.

Will Facebook developers be able to test the behaviour of the custom stories if I upload the simulator build? Maybe they have ways of installing the native Facebook app to the simulator build...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work closely with the people who review the apps and we do have Facebook app on our simulators. So don't worry for that. Please provide complete steps for the team to review your app's functionality. Thanks!